# Spinner isn't working with my custom view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a custom view to draw using my hands. I wanted to add a spinner to select different colors, but for some reason when I click the spinner, it doesn't show any options. I have created an array of 4 colors. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code and output.

**TouchDemo.java**

```
public class TouchDemo extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    Spinner spinner;
    //Custom View
    SingleTouchEventView customView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_touch_demo);
        customView = new SingleTouchEventView(this.getBaseContext(),null);
        ConstraintLayout l = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        l.addView(customView);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.colors,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this,"you have selected " + txt.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

**SingletouchEvent.java**

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {

    private Paint p = new Paint();
    private Path pt = new Path();

    public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        /**
         * these following codes are hardcoded
         */

        super(context, attrs);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setStrokeWidth(3);
        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

    }
```

**activity_touch_demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.makkhay.touchdemo.TouchDemo">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TouchDemo</string>
    <string-array name="colors">
        <item>Purple</item>
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Green</item>
        <item>Yellow</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Here's my output:

[image: Output]

Comment: You're adding your custom `View` on top of the `Spinner`, so no touch events are reaching the `Spinner`. I've not used `ConstraintLayout` yet, but if it behaves like other `ViewGroup`s, you could probably add your custom `View` under the `Spinner` with `l.addView(customView, 0);`. Alternatively, you could put your custom `View` directly in the layout XML, and position it however you'd like in the layout designer.

Comment: Interestingly, adding a zero like you said ( l.addView(customView, 0) worked for me. I'm curious, what does the zero mean in that context? Thank you  @MikeM.

Comment: That argument is the index of the added child in the collection of child `View`s. By specifying `0`, you're making your custom `View` the first (since it's zero-based) child, which means it ends up "on the bottom", with respect to the z-order. The `Spinner` is then on top, and able to receive touch events.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. :)